# Recommendation for the best Talmud Bavli set

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, talmud-bavli, shas

I want to purchase the best Talmud Bavli set that every Jew would dream to have. I have been using Artscrolls Bavli for many years now.

Can you recommend me the best set (price is not an issue)?

Make sure that the text is clear print and not copy and has all of the commentaries.

Comment: Mesivta shas , or Oz vehadar murcheves,but best is relative

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for one with English then IMO Artscroll is the way to go. If you want one with commentaries then Mesivta might be what you are looking for.

The Mesivta gemaras have an explanation in Hebrew on the side, like Artscroll, Tosafos explained in the back, and a collection of many Meforshim (commentaries) in another section in the back.

A set of these can be quite pricey as well as take up a lot of space in you bookcase.

Comment: I use Mesivta a lot, wonderful resource, but I want to add a personal quirk: IMHO there is just nothing like Artscroll for explaining the gemara clearly. If I have a real difficulty in reading: What in the world is the gemara doing? I almost invariably find that Artscroll stops on the problem and tries to deal with it, sometimes when Mesivta just goes right on by.

Answer (score 1):

I love the Oz Vehadar set - it nice and clean, and packed with meforshim - they have tons in the back, plus bonuses like summaries of pesukim that are brought down and gemaros brought down in tosafos in the back. Most bochurim in my yeshiva use it, its great. They also have different types, they have a cheaper red set, and a higher quality nicer black set. I would HIGHLY recommend it.

Comment: They also bring down all the relevant Rambams and Shulchan Aruchs in the back. Its a great balance of a classic gemara, with aids for when one needs them.